# Faces are missing in the textured view

Tags: texturing

I've downloaded a free 3d car model, and everything seems to be fine except one thing: the windows act very weirdly. When in texture view, some of the faces seem like they are missing, while in the non texture view the surface looks solid. The texture is a solid grey square. I'd be very appreciative if someone could help me to fix this. I provided a few screenshots, so it would be easier to understand the issue.

Non textured and textured views
[image]

This is how it's rendering in Blender AND on a game engine (very badly)
[image]

Comment: And here is the UV: http://imgur.com/I4SOlju

Comment: The UV looks really weird. Did it come with the model, or did you do it yourself? And are the overlapping islands intentional?

Comment: [EDIT: See next comment.] Do they flicker? Could be duplicate faces z-fighting. Might also be something odd with the normals (here's info for viewing normal vectors: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/mesh_display.html#mesh-display-normals ).

Comment: Just looked at the UV. It looks like there are several overlaps, which would explain the result. Try moving the faces in the UV so they don't overlap.

Answer (score -1):

It was the issue with the normal vectors. I fixed that by flipping normals on the problem faces. Shame on me, I should have figured that out myself. Thank you, I appreciate your assistance.